# Inserting <span> tags into plain text fields

Tags: 9, wysiwyg

I've been given a content type with content already populated.

There are a number of headings/title fields in the content type and I have been asked to style a sub-section of those fields.

ie:

```
<h1>Title for your local service is styled</h1>
```

has to become:

```
<h1>Title for your <span class="myclass">local service</span> is styled</h1>
```

or something like that.

Is there a way to insert span tags like this into plain text fields? Maybe with a token?

I would like to avoid changing all such fields to formated text fields if possible. Not to mention I've been asked to do this for the node Title which I don't think I can recreate in such a way.

I can add the span to the WYSIWYG editor but would like someway to do this in the plain text fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add a span tag to a plain text field, it will be output as text, not a tag-- that's why it's a "plain text" field.

If you want your text to be formatted, use a formatted text field.

If the requirements have changed and a field which used to contain plain text now needs to have HTML tags, the field type needs to change, too.

### Handling the title

For the node title, there may be some hacky way to add the tags, but I would not try that.  Instead, add another field such as **Formatted page title** to the content type(s) and then put the formatted title there.

The **Title** is also to print the `<title>` of the page, which does not support HTML tags, and having metatags there will also mess up Metatags and other modules using such info.  So if you want a formatted title, that is best as a separate field.